# Xamarin MasterDetailPage fixed Toolbar

Tags: c#, layout, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have implemented a **MasterDetailPage** with **Xamarin Forms**. Currently on Windows tablet only.

I see that there is the **ToolbarItems** that we can add **ToolbarItems** to. But this disappears and only displays as a popup type slidey piece. What I would like is for the toolbar or stack panel to display at the bottom of the MasterDetailPage all the time.

So the MasterDetailPage.Master(Red) stays put as well as the Toolbar/Other Component(Green)
When you select an item in the red it would load the MasterDetailPage.Detail(Blue) as usual.

The important thing is getting the Green Toolbar/other component to display at the bottom all the time.

Is this possible or do I just need to scrap the MasterDetails and use Stackpanels/grid?

I could get the green bar across the blue but really want it across red and blue sections as in the image provided.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as using a master page was appropriate for the dashboard view. I chose to add a StackLayout(User Control) at the bottom of the master view and also the Master Details pages.

It was a bit more duplication but only one line if using a user control.

This gave the illusion that the bar ran across the bottom, when in actual fact it was 2 bars one for the master and one on each of the detail pages.